# synonym for cannibalize?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I'm putting in a supply request at work and I'm asking for a class set of something, plus a few extras:

> class set of 30 + 5 to cannibalize as parts inevitably go missing

I've looked up definitions...

> a : to take salvageable parts from (something, such as a disabled
> machine) for use in building or repairing another machine
>
> b : to make use of (a part taken from one thing) in building, repairing, or
> creating something else

and [synonyms](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/cannibalize), but haven't found a single word synonym to use--only phrases such as "dismantle for parts."

Comment: Considering we generally use it in the phrase "cannibalize for parts", I'm almost tempted to post "dismantle" an answer, but you've already ruled that one out.

Comment: "Part out" is an idiom with essentially the same meaning as this sense of "cannibalize".

Comment: You need to explain why *cannibalize* is unacceptable.

Comment: Better asked on related tech SE. I'm quite sure there *is* a word the geeks use.

Comment: "+ 5 to serve as parts donors" is probably the easiest option.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is unclear why the term "cannibalize" (*for parts*, implied) is unacceptable in the given context.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, while *cannibalise* is OK, the simpler "30 sets + 5 *for spare parts *" or even just "30 sets + 5 *spares*" is just as clear.

In general *cannibalise* and many of the suggestions in other answers work better applied to existing inventory, perhaps already past its best, rather than for new acquisitions.

Comment: yeah, that's why I was looking for another word/phrase

Answer (score 0):

In this context, I invite you to consider using "to repurpose" or "for repairs", for instance "class set of 30 + 5 for repurposing, as parts inevitably go missing"

Answer (score 0):

First of all, *cannibalise* is an accepted form for taking apart machines for their parts. It is also used in French (i.e. cannibaliser) and Dutch (i.e. kannibaliseren).

Recycle ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/recycle#English), 2018):

> To break down and reuse component materials.

E.g. "+ 5 units to recycle"

OR

Salvage ([Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/learner-english/salvage_1), 2018):

> to save things from a place where other things have been damaged or lost

E.g. "+ 5 units for salvaging parts"

Answer (score 0):

A common term is [teardown](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/teardown) as in an act of completely dismantling something.
often used with the intention of rebuilding as in racing cars
see also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_teardown

> class set of 30 + 5 to **teardown** as parts inevitably go missing

Answer (score 0):

stripped out is a term for dismantling a machine for parts

Comment: _Strip out_ is a good answer. It'd be a better answer for _this_ site if it were sourced, perhaps including a dictionary definition. Perhaps take a look at [how to answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).